# How do I set the ARN for a AWS SAM Local Lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I would like to set the ARN for my java lambda function that I run locally with SAM Local in Eclipse.

In my Junit-Test I can do this by setting it with `context.setInvokedFunctionArn` but how can I do this if I run this as SAM Local? I am guessing I do this in the serverless.template, but I couldn't find how to do this exactly.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAM local is using [lambci/docker-lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) project under the hood, which allows specifying function ARN using `AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN` enviroment variable, client/invoke logic for [java](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda/blob/master/java8/run/lambda-runtime-mock/src/main/java/lambdainternal/LambdaRuntime.java#L63)